# # encoding: utf-8 don't working ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, utf-8

I'm using ruby 1.9.1 for my project.
So I need remove some comments from string which paste from word.
such as:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
     <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
      <o:RelyOnVML/>
      <o:AllowPNG/>
     </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml><![endif]-->
```

So I write a function to remove it in helper with `text.gsub(/<!--(.*?)-->/s, "")` and added `# encoding: utf-8` on the top helper file rb, also define `config.encoding = "utf-8"` in application.rb  but it seem not work for me.
The error I get

```
    ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible encoding regexp match (Windows-31J regexp with UTF-8 string))
```

Do you have any support for me in this case? Thanks!

Comment: try this `text.gsub(/<!--(.*?)-->/m, "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a DOTALL modifier `s` in ruby. Just change `s` modifier to `m` to make it work.

```
text.gsub(/<!--(.*?)-->/m, "")
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/tcKjzHpMnE)

And also you don't need to capture any characters , just `/<!--.*?-->/m` would be fine.